# How to pass array into the where condition?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have dynamic where conditions. They consist of the following array:

```
array:2 [
  "brand_name" => array:2 [
    0 => "a"
    1 => "b"
  ]
  "category_type" => array:1 [
    0 => "AA"
  ]
]
```

I need to apply where conditions to my query.

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
$sql = " select * from products as p";

$i = 0;
foreach ($wheres as $key => $value) {
    if ($i === 0) {
        $sql .= " WHERE";
    } else {
        $sql .= " AND";
    }
    $sql.= " te.$key IN (:$key)";
    $i +=1;
}
```

I am not sure how to assign the value to the query. If I had single where condition, I did something like this:

```
$params = array(
            $ids,
        );
        $query = $em->getConnection()->executeQuery(
            $sql,
            $params,
            array(
                \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_STR_ARRAY,
                \PDO::PARAM_INT,
            )
        );
        $records = $query->fetchAll();
```

But I don't know how to fix where where conditions are in dynamic.

Comment: Since you're using doctrine, I strongly advise you to use the query builder

Comment: Agree with Cid, custom queries are used for really complicated operations, for what you're trying to do query builder is perfect - https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/query-builder.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very easy using the query builder. It's the kind of thing it was designed for.

Something like this would take you there:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');

$suffix = 0;
foreach ($conditions as $key => $value) {
    $parameter = 'query_' . $suffix++;

    $qb->andWhere("p.$key IN :$parameter")
        ->setParamter($parameter, $value);
}

$records = $qb->getQuery()->getResult()
```

You'll need to make adjustments to suit your data model. In your question you are selecting `products as p`, but then you are trying to select from `te`, so I guess some pieces are missing from the puzzle.

But you should be able to finish it from here.